# Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root

Tags: mysql, macos

I am getting the following message error when I try to open my connections in mysql workbench. Am using Mysql workbench 6.3 (64 -bits) on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5. i have tried my best and couldn't resolve this eroor please someone help me

Comment: In my view it will be hard to help you here, just too many things can go wrong. mySql not started, incorrect port, firewall, incompatible versions, etc. Try a mySql forum instead!

Comment: where is mysql on your local mac system or linux server...

Comment: MAC system. I followed the tutorials for installing mysql workbench from youtube step by step still it does not work for me

Comment: Can you telnet to port 3306? You might get some jibberish but you shoud be able to tell whether it connected and if MySQL emitted its version number.

Comment: when i m setting up a new database connection with port number 3306 it throws that error. Also  the the host was 127.0.0.1. I still dint know why the connection isn't establishing?